# Simple question about the name of an expression containing ? :

Tags: c#

Anyone knows what is the name of this expression?

```
bool result = array[i] == 1 ? true : false;
```

Comment: That's a ternary operator

Comment: `bool result = array[i] == 1;` is a shorter version (no need in `? true : false`)

Answer (score 2):

The operator `? :` is commonly known as the [ternary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) operator. It is known as the ternary operator in many languages, not just C#.

It has the syntax:

```
condition ? consequent : alternative
```

From the documentation linked above:

> You can use the following mnemonic device to remember how the
>   conditional operator is evaluated:
>
> ```
> is this condition true ? yes : no
> ```

It is short-hand for a regular if/else statement.

```
int result;
if (condition)
{
    result = 1;
}
else
{
    result = 0;
}
```

The equivalent of the above in ternary syntax would be:

```
int result = condition ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional operator expression [?: Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).